# Error on string to datatime Conversion in sql

Tags: sql

I have a problem on converting string ( in 'DD.MM.YYYY' format ) to Datetime ( in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format). You can see the related example and result in the below:

```
DECLARE @DATE date  
DECLARE @RESULT datetime 
SET @DATE = '12.04.2013' /* DD.MM.YYYY */  
SET @RESULT = CONVERT(datetime,@DATE,104)
SELECT @RESULT
```

Result is : `2013-12-04 00:00:00.000 in YYYY-MM-DD`

Problem is that sql converts day of the @DATE variable to month of the @Result variable.

Is there any way to correct this?

Thank you

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it works for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try like this

```
 SELECT convert(datetime, '12.04.2013', 104)
```

or

in you code just change type of `datetime` variable to `varchar(15)`

```
DECLARE @DATE varchar(15)--date

DECLARE @RESULT datetime

 --because in below line if the variable type is datetime than value is get 
 --converted to datetime and consider 12 as month and 04 as day but if the 
 --variable type is  varchar  than this doent happen
SET @DATE = '12.04.2013' --/* DD.MM.YYYY */.

--now this will work as you need 
SET @RESULT = CONVERT(datetime,@DATE,104)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `datetime` has no inherent *format*, it's just a datetime with a value. You have to convert it to `varchar`:

```
DECLARE @RESULT varchar(10)
SET @RESULT = CONVERT(varchar(10),@DATE,126)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12466/0)